# jQuery Menu - addClass X removeClass Y and Z

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have a List for a Menu and I want to Add or Remove a class to the Item Link, as well as hide previous applied classes to the same list applying only the class to the clicked Item.
In addition I also want to display a hidden div for the item, hiding any div triggered by the click on any of the other items.

This is working for me, but I feel like I'm missing something that will make it simpler, maybe I'm wrong, or maybe I'm not, I'd like to know your opinion and suggestions.

```
$("ul li:first-child").click(function(){
    $("ul li:first-child").toggleClass('lihover');
    $("ul li:nth-child(2), ul li:nth-child(3)").removeClass('lihover');
    $(".item1").fadeToggle();
    $(".item2, .item3").hide();
});
```

Basically the fiddle will talk for myself.
Please Check it for a better understanding.
http://jsfiddle.net/fyjHk/1/

Keep in mind, this is working as intended, I just want to know if there's any other way to do this with less steps (code). This because, imagine if I have a menu with 20 Items, list them all to hide and/or show is a bit polluted in the code IMO, so maybe there's a way to simplify this.

Keep in mind I'm new to jQuery and Javascript, take this with a bit of salt.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You may try http://jsfiddle.net/fyjHk/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd go with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fyjHk/10/.

It reuses much more code, keeping things clean. It also utilizes some handy jQuery functions to make things more compact and generic.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li data-id='item1'>item 1</li>
    <li data-id='item2'>item 2</li>
    <li data-id='item3'>item 3</li>
    <li>hide all</li>
</ul>

<div id="item1" class="item hide">Content For Item 1</div>
<div id="item2" class="item hide">Content For Item 2</div>
<div id="item3" class="item hide">Content For Item 3</div>
```

By letting the `li` elements hold the information about which `div` they are coupled with, you save a lot of JS code and make it easier to add and remove items. Also, to identify one element its always best to use an `id` and use a `class` for a group of elements who share a certain logic. In this case, all `div`s items, but also have an id to be coupled with the `li`.

Javascript:

```
$("ul li[data-id]").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('lihover').siblings().removeClass('lihover');
    $("#" + $(this).data("id")).fadeToggle().siblings(".item").hide();
});

$("ul li:last-child").click(function(){
    $(".item").hide();
    $("ul li[data-id]").removeClass('lihover');
});
```

One of the nice things about letting the `li` elements hold the info is that you can cut down on code duplication and write cleaner selectors. The [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function, you can easily select the other elements instead of having to define them all in your code.

Comment: Hello and Thank you for the reply. Your fiddle isn't exactly working like mine. Am I missing something? / What I mean is, that the class, when i click on the item 1, its applyed, but when i click on item 2, the class from item 1 remains. Also, the div content isnt being displayed.

Comment: @HélioC Sorry, I made a typo. See the updated fiddle.

Comment: ^ This! Thank you very much for the time and the explanation on those topics. It cleared many things up. Specially on the addition of the data-id to couple the specific div. Marking as the solution. Thank you again. HC

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid all the duplication, by doing something like this:

```
$("ul li").on('click', function(){
    $('.items div').fadeOut(0);    
    $('.items div').eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(300);
});
```

You'll probably have to edit it a bit to add and remove the active class.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fyjHk/7/)**

Comment: Hello Nick, thank you for your reply.
If i understand correctly, what your code 'says' is: All .items fadeOut on Click and THEN the Item inside the .items div that matches the POSITION of the clicked li will fadeIn. Is this correct?

Comment: @HélioC Yep that's correct, I'm using `.index()` to get the index of whichever `li` was clicked, and then we can pass that `index` into the `eq()` method, so we show the relevant `item div`

Comment: Got it then. I edited your fiddle to fulfill the main question that poses in the title of my question... if you want to add it to your answer so it makes it 100% complete, you can check it here. http://jsfiddle.net/fyjHk/11/ . Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest i could see:

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    var index = _this.index();

    // Reset
    var hover = _this.hasClass('lihover');
    $('ul li').removeClass('lihover');

    if(_this.hasClass('hide-all')) {
         $('.item').hide();   
    } else {
        if (!hover) {
           _this.addClass('lihover');
        }
        $('.item').eq(index).fadeToggle();
        $('.item').eq(index).siblings('.item').hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fyjHk/4/
new fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fyjHk/12/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking when I said (less steps). I go only one issue, that is: When You click item, if you click it again... the class applied remains the 'hover' instead or restore the initial one.

Comment: Added what you are asking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
    var li = $(this).parent().children(),
        sel = li.index($(this)) + 1;
    if(sel == 4)
        return $('.hide').hide();
    li.each(function(i){
        $('.item' + i)[i == sel ? "fadeIn" : "hide"]();
    });
});
```